# Initialize an array inside a structure

Tags: c, struct

I have this structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    union{
        int bytex[8];
        int bytey[7];
   }Value ;
   int cod1;
   int cod;
} test;
```

and want to initialize the constant `test` as follow:

```
const test T{
.Value.bytex = {0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44,0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44},
.cod1=0,
.cod=1,
};
```

I am getting the following error

```
Expected primary-expression before '.' token
```

This initialization is however correct:

```
const test T{
{0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44,0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44},
.cod1=0,
.cod=1,
};
```

Do you have any Idea ?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, this isn't close to ressembling struct/union initialization syntax. Fix:

```
const test T = 
{
  .Value.bytex = { 0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44,0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44 },
  .cod1 = 0,
  .cod  = 1,
};
```

Second, if you have the option to use standard C, you can drop the inner variable name:

```
typedef struct
{
  union {
    int bytex[8];
    int bytey[7];
  };
  int cod1;
  int cod;
} test;

const test T = 
{
  .bytex = { 0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44,0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44 },
  .cod1 = 0,
  .cod  = 1,
};
```

Comment: @FiddlingBits Nope, could be anywhere. This is the C11 anonymous struct/union feature.